# Функция как параметр другой функции

Tags: python

Вопрос такой, вот есть у меня код проверки email допустим:

```
def CorrectEmail(email):
    if email.count('@') > 1 or email.count('@') == 0:
        return (False, 'Неверное количество знаков @')
    [name,domain] = email.split('@')
    if len(domain) < 3:
        return (False, 'Доменное имя короче 3 символов')
    if len(domain) > 256:
        return (False, 'Доменное имя длиннее 256 символов')
    if domain.count('.') == 0:
    return (False, 'Доменное имя не содержит точки')
includedomain = domain.split('.')
# список с кодами корректных сиволов a-z - и _
correctchrlist = list(range(ord('a'),ord('z')+1))
correctchrlist.extend([ord('-'), ord('_')])
for k in includedomain:
    # проверяем нет ли пустых подстрок в домене
    if k == '':
        return (False, 'Доменное имя содержит пустую строку между точками')
    # проверяем нет ли нелегальных символов в подстроках в домене
    for n in k:
        if ord(n) not in correctchrlist:
            errormsg = "Недопустимый символ " + n
            return (False, errormsg)
    if (k[0] == '-') or (k[len(k)-1] == '-'):
        return (False, 'Доменное имя не может начинаться/заканчиваться знаком "-"')
if len(name) > 128:
    return (False, 'Имя длиннее 128 символов')
# Добавляем в список корректных символов . ; " ! : ,
correctchrlist.extend([ord('.'),ord(';'),ord('"')])
onlyinquoteschrlist = [ord('!'), ord(','), ord(':')]
correctchrlist.extend(onlyinquoteschrlist)
# Проверка на парные кавычки
if name.count('"')%2 != 0:
    return (False, "Непарные кавычки")
# Переменные для отслеживания точки и открывающихся кавычек
doubledot = False
inquotes = False
for k in name:
    if (k == '"'):
        inquotes = not inquotes
    if (ord(k) in onlyinquoteschrlist) and (inquotes == False):
        return (False, "Недопустимый символ вне кавычек")
    if ord(k) not in correctchrlist:
        errormsg = "Недопустимый символ " + k
        return (False, errormsg)
    # проверка на две точки подряд
    if (k == '.'):
        if doubledot == True:
            return (False, "Две точки в имени")
        else:
            doubledot = True
return (True, "")
```

и пусть будет вот такой еще код:

```
def register():
    reg = input('Хотите зарегистрироваться? ')
    if not reg == 'yes':
        print('Пока!')
        return False

    nick = input('Введите свой никнейм:' )

    while True:
        password = input('Введите пароль:' )
        password2 = input('Подтвердите пароль:' )
        if password == password2:
            break
        print('Пароли не совпадают!')

    email = input('Введите email:' )
    age = input('Введите дату рождения (DD.MM.YYYY):' )
    print(nick + ', спасибо за регистрацию, на ваш email ' + email + ' выслано сообщение с кодом')
    return True
```

Вопрос такой, как во второй код использовать `def CorrectEmail(email)`. Чтобы например в строке `email = input('Введите email:' )` была проверка правильности email. Ну и вообще как правильно функцию в функцию "подключать" скажем так.

Comment: Постарайся давать более осмысленные названия вопросам.

Comment: У вас слишком много "лирики" в вопросе, которая никому не интересна. Постарайтесь задавать вопрос по существу. Все здесь когда-то начинали с малого.

Comment: Благодарю за замечание, хорошо, буду только по существу

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Смотрите, функция возвращает какое-то значение, которое потом можно использовать дальше, например

```
a = getA()
b = getB(a)
c = getC(b)
```

НО! Мы ведь можем избавиться от промежуточных переменных, передавая в функцию вызов другой функции

```
с = getC(getB(getA()))
```

Сначала выполнится самая вложенная функция, потом следующая и так до `getC`. Поэтому, в вашем случае

```
email = input('Введите email:' )
CorrectEmail(email)

// можно просто заменить на
CorrectEmail(input('Введите email:' ))
```

Но если нужно еще обращаться к email, то лучше хранить его в переменной

**UPD** 
Что бы проверка работала, нужно использовать значения из функции `CorrectEmail`

```
[success, error] = CorrectEmail(input('Введите email:' ))
if (not success):
  print(error)
```

Comment: Попробовал 
`email = input('Введите email:' )
CorrectEmail(email)` 
И когда ввожу допустим gfdgd должен выдавать ошибку,  но он этого не делает и пропускает дальше не указывая на ошибочный email

Comment: Надо значение то использовать, в условии, например

Comment: немного не понял, можно попросить объяснить, пожалуйста

Comment: @JDie добавил код

Comment: спасибо за помощь и ответ